# Incorrect regex in Cmake rule

Tags: regex, cmake

I want to exclude only one absolute path from the returned runtime dependencies list. I use regex for that, but I can't figure out CMake's regex format.
It works in the online checkers, but it doesn't in the Cmake.

How to exclude only this path "/lib64"?

The code below:

```
install(CODE [[
      file(GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES
        EXECUTABLES $<TARGET_FILE:myApp1> $<TARGET_FILE:myApp2> $<TARGET_FILE:myApp3>
        RESOLVED_DEPENDENCIES_VAR RESOLVED_DEPS
        UNRESOLVED_DEPENDENCIES_VAR UNRESOLVED_DEPS
        CONFLICTING_DEPENDENCIES_PREFIX CONFLICTING_DEPENDENCIES
        POST_EXCLUDE_REGEXES "^(\/lib64)$"
      )
...
]]
```

Produces a warning:

```
  when parsing string

    ^(\/lib64)$

  Invalid escape sequence \/
```

If I change it to "^(/lib64)$" - it just does not excludes it...

Comment: I'm not a CMake person, but the examples I can find have no quotes around the regex. `/` is not a regex special character so there is no need to backslash it. For what it's worth, the parentheses are also superfluous.

Comment: Does `"^/lib64$"` work for you?

Comment: Hmm, Duck Duck Going some more finds examples with double quotes around the regex more than without.

Comment: Looking at the documentation some more, I guess you want to exclude _files in_ that directory; so you probably want something like `"^/lib64/[^/]*$"`

Comment: @tripleee Wow...you're absolutely right. I forgot it returns full paths to files. That's why it didn't match. But your example works!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to exclude files *in that directory;* so you probably want something like `"^/lib64/[^/]*$"`

The `[^/]*$` part is superfluous if you want to match subdirectories, too; then just matching on the prefix `"^/lib64/"` should be sufficient.